# Excel Sumproduct with requirements and indefinite list (entire column)

Tags: excel, finance, sumifs

**Desired Ouput:**
Total expenses for each month.

**Input:**
One or indefinately many items. For each item there are:

1. Start month
2. Interval in months
3. Cost
4. 'active-inactive' flag

I got pretty far using SUMPRODUCT, see the example below.

[image: Example]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($I$2:$I$6="x");--(MOD(MONTH(O2)-MONTH($M$2:$M$6);$L$2:$L$6)=0);$K$2:$K$6)
```

Where:

- `$I$2:$I$6` --> 'active-inactive' flag of the items
- `O2` --> month for which to calculate the total expenses
- `$M$2:$M$6` --> 'Start month' of the items
- `$L$2:$L$6` --> 'Interval in months' of the items
- `$K$2:$K$6` --> 'Cost of the items

**Problem:**
The formula only works with defined ranges (`$I$2:$I$6`). However, I want the formula to work for any amount of items without adjusting the range (`$I:$I`). All my trials resulted either in errors or excessively long calculation times.

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the following to find the last row with data:

```
=INDEX($M:$M;MATCH(1e99;$M:$M))
```

This will find the last row in column M and use that to set the last cell in that column.

So adding that to your formula we get:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($I$2:INDEX($I:$I;MATCH(1e99;$M:$M))="x")*(MOD(MONTH(O2)-MONTH($M$2:INDEX($M:$M;MATCH(1e99;$M:$M)));$L$2:INDEX($L:$L;MATCH(1e99;$M:$M)))=0)*$K$2:INDEX($K:$K;MATCH(1e99;$M:$M)))
```

And now the dataset size is dynamic based on the last row in column M with dates in it.

Comment: Works as advertised. Thank you very much!